# At least probability question

Tags: probability, self-study, binomial-distribution

At a university 60% of the students are male and 40% are female. If ten students are selected at random,

1. What is the probability that we have exactly seven females?
   I tried $0.4^7\cdot0.6\cdot3 = 0.00294912$ for this.
2. What is the probability of selecting at least seven females?

I tried adding the sums of the probability of 7, 8, 9, and 10 females in the group.
0.003447194

Both of my answers were counted wrong. I was told that this is the correct way to solve this. Any help?

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and modify your question to take into account the information [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Comment: Thanks for adding the tag, but you still need to show us what you've tried and explain where your difficulties are.

Comment: Consider: what events (situations) are included in "At least seven females"?

Comment: Your idea (of adding the probability of 7, 8, 9 and 10 females) is correct.

Answer (score 2):

In (1) you haven't accounted for all the different ways that you can get 7 females and 3 males.

In (2) your idea was correct (of adding the probability of 7, 8, 9 and 10 females), but if you have the probability in (1) wrong, you'll have the same mistake.

(You might want to read about the binomial distribution.)